# how to overload an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**thsi is my code:**

```
var data_book_list=new Array();
var test_type= jQuery('#test_type').val('list1');
function bookList() {
         jQuery.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "array.php",
             dataType: 'json',
             data: {book:book},
             success: function(data){
                         for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                            {
                             data_list.push(data[i]);
                            }
    }
    });
```

**imagine database like:** list1 has `a1,a2,a3` & list2 `b1,b2,b3`

if i selected value `list1` ajax get that value and sent it to php.
php using where case so it gives back to ajax`a1,a2,a3` 
now data has `a1,a2,a3` i make it that a new array form for loop like `['a1','a2','a3']`
i push this to a `var data_book_list=[];`
it work great.

but my problem is if i select option `list2`
  data has`b1,b2,b3` and  `data_book_list=[]` has `a1,a2,a3`
for loop push data `b1,b2,b3` to array data_book_list it will extend   like  `['a1','a2','a3', 'b1','b2','b3']`

but i need like this  `['b1','b2','b3]` in array data_book_list. how to clear or overload old  array data automatically.

Comment: Can't you just clear `data_book_list` at the start of the `bookList` function with `data_book_list = []`? (Although you seem to call it just `data_list` inside the Ajax callback...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep track of all the values retrieved so far, then you will have to use an object and have the value as array, corresponding to the keys.

```
var data_book_list_obj = {};
var test_type= jQuery('#test_type').val('list1');

    function bookList() {
             jQuery.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "array.php",
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: {book: test_type},
                 success: function(data){
                             for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                                {
                                 data_book_list_obj[test_type] = data_book_list_obj[test_type] || [];
data_book_list_obj[test_type].push(data[i]);
                                }
                }
   });
```

Or if you need only the recent information, then just assign the value.

```
var data_book_list=new Array();
var test_type= jQuery('#test_type').val('list1');
function bookList() {
         jQuery.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "array.php",
             dataType: 'json',
             data: {book: test_type},
             success: function(data){
                 // Edit removed for loop wrongly put here
                 data_book_list = data;           
             }
});
```

Comment: Try printing out the value in what is coming from the server. Like inside the for loop, just all the line console.log(data[i]);
If no loop, then just print the array like console.log(data);
And see what is printed in the console.